MySQL Sorting Using MAX() For GROUP BY Is Returning Malformed Data
Okay, I'm absolutely flummoxed trying to understand what's going on here.
Everywhere I'm reading it is suggested to use MAX()/MIN() on a data column with a GROUP BY in order to get the highest/lowest value for each group of data. Yet every attempt I try to retrieve the data in such a way, it returns the max/min of one column, but then displays that data with the ID from a different row?!
I've distilled my query below to the simplest level, just the subscript that I'm trying to JOIN later with another larger query:
SELECT studentID, studentCourseID, MAX(dateCreated) AS dateCreated
FROM courseAttempts
JOIN courses ON courseID = studentCourseID AND courseActive = 1 
WHERE studentID IN (100,101,102,103) AND studentBlocked = 0
GROUP BY studentCourseID

Below is the data that the script is able to retrieve without the use of MAX() or GROUP BY



studentID
courseID
dateCreated




100
39
2023-09-07 02:48:46.000


102
39
2023-12-24 02:57:07.000



If I run the script above with the MAX() and GROUP BY I get:



studentID
courseID
dateCreated




100
39
2023-12-24 02:57:07.000



That's the right date, but the wrong ID. That's malformed unusable data.
How is this supposed to work?
It should return



studentID
courseID
dateCreated




102
39
2023-12-24 02:57:07.000




You are selecting two columns studentID and courseID, but only group by courseID. Is that intentional? IIRC there is a setting which disallow such queries.

Sorry, it should be studentCourseID for the data column that it retrieves and groups by. But even if I remove the JOIN, the results are still the same.

Please include the full output you expect.  Do you really expect just a single row?

@BenjaminWKI Why do you select two columns without an aggregate function (studentID and studentCourseID), but only use one column in the GROUP BY part (studentCourseID)?

I included the additional JOIN and columns in the example query here to assist identifying if they're the possible cause. But in hindsight, it was redundant as the most basic query using just the 2 needed data columns
SELECT studentID, MAX(dateCreated) AS dateCreated FROM courseAttempts WHERE studentID IN (100,102) GROUP BY studentCourseID
still returns the row with a mismatched ID to date which is the real issue here.

@BenjaminWKI You might want to look at https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/group-by-handling.html on GROUP BY statements with columns which are not listed in the GROUP BY part.

Use a windowing function:
WITH cte AS (
  SELECT
    studentID,
    studentCourseID,
    dateCreated, 
    ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY studentCourseID ORDER BY dateCreated DESC) AS row_num
  FROM courseAttempts
  JOIN courses ON courseID = studentCourseID AND courseActive = 1 
  WHERE studentID IN (100,101,102,103) AND studentBlocked = 0
)
SELECT * FROM cte WHERE row_num = 1


Thanks, mate.  This does return the result I am looking for.
However, I'm still trying to figure out just why is the MAX() with GROUP BY option is accepted as the solution for other cases similar to mine, yet my implementation is returning unusable (outright incorrect) data.

@BenjaminWKI MySQL is unique in that it allows non-aggregated columns to be omitted from the group by clause if the ONLY_FULL_GROUP_BY SQL mode is disabled (default in older versions), and if so it picks a random row (usually the first row it finds) for each unique combination of the columns specified in the group by clause. You're selecting studentID with aggregation, but omitting it from the group by, so it's finding the max date for the course, but picking a random row to supply the studentID.

Makes sense. However, it still is incomprehensible that, unless one knows of this inconsistency, they might accept the data returned, without any error, that is just outright malformed.

@BenjaminWKI this behaviour is documented. Caveat emptor...

In your query, studentID in the SELECT list is neither an aggregated column nor a column stated in the GROUP BY clause. This is NOT allowed in the earlier SQL standards (SQL-92 and before) . However, SQL-1999 and later permits such nonaggregated column , ON ONE CONDITION, which is the non aggregated column MUST be functionally dependent on the columns in the GROUP BY clause. See: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/group-by-handling.html 
For example, in an e-commerce platform, a user_id is unique. For every user_id, there is a unique user_name associated to it.(Note: the relationship should be defined in table structure, such as using PK/UNIQUE key) In this case, the user_name is functionally dependent on the user_id. Under such circumstance, if you want to get the total spending by each user_id, it's legit to put user_name in the SELECT list without defining it in the GROUP BY clause:
select user_name , user_id , sum(spending)
...
group by user_id
;

But in your case, from the data without the use of MAX() or GROUP BY,
studentID   courseID    dateCreated
100         39          2023-09-07 02:48:46.000
102         39          2023-12-24 02:57:07.000

we can already see it is possible for a studentCourseID to have more than one studentID. Therefore, studentID is not functionally dependent on studentCourseID.(The reason that your query does not raise an error is because ONLY_FULL_GROUP_BY is not defined in the system variable sql_mode. ) So you should either put it in the GROUP BY list, or omit it from the SELECT list.  Otherwise, how can MySQL know which studentID to return ? (Especially in the case of sum() ,when every studentID from a studentCourseID contributes to the aggregate value)
Your might think that MySQL should just automatically return the studentID which has the latest date for a courseID.  Unfortunately, it does not work that way. We have to do some extra work. Here are the two steps to do the job:
First of all, we need to get the max date for each studentCourseID:
select studentCourseID, max(dateCreated) as maxdate
from derived_table
;

Then, we perform a JOIN on our original table and the aggregate table from previous step:
select t1.studentID, t1.studentCourseID, t1.dateCreated
from derived_table t1
join (select studentCourseID, max(dateCreated) as maxdate
     from derived_table) t2
on t1.studentCourseID=t2.studentCourseID and t1.dateCreated=t2.maxdate
;


Thank you for the assistance. This makes sense as I believe many of the "MAX() with GROUP BY" solutions I was looking at were pretty old and probably worked with ONLY_FULL_GROUP_BY enabled, which isn't on my system.
If I were to use your recommended method of joining to a subquery, I would need to join on the courseID and dateCreated data columns. If neither of these data columns are indexed, would it affect the query performance?

If neither of these data columns are indexed, the performance will be negatively impacted. And I would suggest using a composite index i.e. (studentCourseID,dateCreated) , as the JOIN condition requires both expressions to be true.
